# 'OdbcConnection' is ambiguous in vb.net interop application

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, office-interop

I have the below code in my VB.NET Windows Forms application:

```
Case "DB2"
    Try
        Dim row As DataRow

        Using cnDB2 As New OdbcConnection(source_cnString)
            Dim drDB2 As OdbcDataReader = Nothing
            Dim cmdDB2 As New OdbcCommand(dtSource, cnDB2)

            cnDB2.Open()
            drDB2 = cmdDB2.ExecuteReader

            While drDB2.Read
                row = dsSourceData.Tables(tableName).NewRow()
                Dim iCell As Integer
```

but I am getting a compile error:

```
'OdbcConnection' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, System.Data.Odbc'
```

I have these **Imports** in the class:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Text
```

Comment: Can you use System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection instead just OdbcConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the error output, OdbcConnection exists in both of the 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' and 'System.Data.Odbc' namespaces. You will have to specify which you are using by putting the full namespace in your code.

```
Using cnDB2 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(source_cnString)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by conflicting namespaces. The one in `System.Data.Odbc` and the one in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, your only possibility here is to specify exactly what namespace you intend to use. You could type the full qualified namespace (`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection` and so on for every Odbc class) or use a simple shortcut to abbreviate your typing.

Try to add this [Imports statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) at the beginning of your code file

```
Imports NetOdbc = System.Data.Odbc
```

and then in your code

```
Case "DB2"
    Try
        Dim row As DataRow

        Using cnDB2 As New NetOdbc.OdbcConnection(source_cnString)
            Dim drDB2 As NetOdbc.OdbcDataReader = Nothing
            Dim cmdDB2 As New NetOdbc.OdbcCommand(dtSource, cnDB2)

            cnDB2.Open()
            drDB2 = cmdDB2.ExecuteReader

            While drDB2.Read
                row = dsSourceData.Tables(tableName).NewRow()
                Dim iCell As Integer
```